# Get current property value reference inside SCSS

Tags: sass, reference, row

I do have a grid with multiple rows, each having set a transform operation:

row 1: `transform: translateY(10px);`

row 2: `transform: translateY(20px);`

row 2: `transform: translateY(40px);`

I would like to ***incrementally*** withdraw 5 pixels from each translate operation, to get something like:

row 1: 10 - **1**x5 = 5 => `transform: translateY(0px);`

row 2: 20 - **2**x5 = 10 =>`transform: translateY(10px);`

row 2: 40 - **3**x5 = 25 =>`transform: translateY(25px);`

For this I would need to get a reference to old set value of the `translateY()` operation. Is this possible/doable in SCSS only?

Comment: Please update your question with information about how rows of your grid are referenced in CSS. Is it `.rowN` or `:nth-child()` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question have no information about how your grid rows are referenced in CSS, so I've assumed that they're marked as `.rowN` where `N` is row number starting from 1. Of course this can be easily changed in code below. Example includes simple implementation of `pow()` function because your `10px, 20px, 40px...` sequence seems to be `(2^(n-1))*10px`.

```
@function pow($base, $exp) {
  @if ($exp == 0) {
    @return 1;
  }
  @if ($exp == 1) {
    @return $base;
  }
  $r: 1;
  @for $n from 0 through $exp - 1 {
    $r: $r * $base;
  }
  @return $r;
}

@for $n from 1 through 3 {
  .row#{$n} {
    transform: translateY(#{pow(2, $n - 1) * 10px - $n * 5px});
  }
}
```